# I can't download or open the pdf download with laravel 7, Php : 7.2.5 , barryvdh/laravel-dompdf : 2.0

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-7, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

Meu config.App.php

- providers  `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class`
- aliases -  `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,`

My route

- `Route::get('/pedidos/pdf','PdfController@gerarPdf');`

My Controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function gerarPdf()
    {      
        $data = ['title' => 'Laravel 7 Generate PDF From View Example Tutorial'];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('Pdf.PdfTeste', $data);
        $pdf->download('Nicesnippets.pdf');
        return $pdf;        
    }
}
```

my view Pdf.PdfTeste :

> ## leo

But when I make the request, using either download() or stream, it always returns the same thing.

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w3oz.png)
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPQSH.png)